# How can I display or hide a table column based on the parameters passed to an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS Report with 4 parameters. Parameter 1 = Country. The list of valid values for country is: 1,2,3,4,9,16.

When parameter is in 1,2,3,4 I'd like to set the visibility of a textbox to true. If parameter is 9 or 16 then I'd like to hide the column.

I've tried:

```
=IIF((Parameters!CountryList.Value in (1,2,20,21), true,false))
```

"In" is not a valid operator in Visual Basic. I feel like this should be easy but haven't found an "in" equivalent. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: So where did the values 20 and 21 come from? Anyway, if you want to hide based on 2 values. Use `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Based on the least parameters to test.

```
=IIF(Parameters!CountryList.Value ="9" OR Parameters!CountryList.Value = "16", False,True)
```

Comment: I used this expression: =IIF((Parameters!CountryList.Value = "1" OR Parameters!CountryList.Value = "2" OR Parameters!CountryList.Value = "20" OR Parameters!CountryList.Value = "21" ,True,False)) But am getting an error that reads: " The Visibilit.Hidden expression for the text box contains an error: ')' expected".

Comment: I think your answer is very close I'll do some fine tuning till it works. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the outer parenthesis. You only need 1 set. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I had an extra parenthesis =IFF() worked but =IIF(()) didn't work. Again thanks!